# How can I create PDF Service with a cocoa-applescript (AppleScriptObjc) application?

Tags: applescript-objc

I decided to be foolhardy and write my own Email PDF with GMail PDF service and learn AppleScriptObjC at the same time. I've got everything working, and except for actually being able to accept the file from the print dialog.

Here's what the code looks like so far:
    script gmailpdfAppDelegate
        property parent : class "NSObject"

```
    property recipientField : missing value
    property subjectField : missing value
    property fromField : missing value
    property passwordField : missing value
    property messageField : missing value
    property pdfFile : missing value


    on ButtonHandlerCancel_(sender)
        quit
    end ButtonHandlerCancel_

    on ButtonHandlerSend_(sender)
        set recipient to recipientField's stringValue()
        set subject to subjectField's stringValue()
        set fromUser to fromField's stringValue()
        set pw to passwordField's stringValue()
        set message to messageField's stringValue()

        set sendEmailScript to (current application's NSBundle's mainBundle()'s pathForResource_ofType_("sendEmail", "")) as string
        set emailserverInfo to " -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu '" & fromUser & "' -xp '" & pw & "' -m '" & message & "' "
        do shell script quoted form of sendEmailScript & " -t " & recipient & " -u " & subject & " -f '" & fromUser & "' " & emailserverInfo
        quit
    end ButtonHandlerSend_

    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened
        set fromField's stringValue to do shell script "defaults read org.ryancollins.GMail-PDF 'fromDefault'"
        set passwordField's stringValue to do shell script "security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -ga gmailpdf |ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: \"(.*)\"$/'"
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits
        set fromDefault to fromField's stringValue()
        do shell script "defaults write org.ryancollins.GMail-PDF 'fromDefault' '" & fromDefault & "'"

        set passwordDefault to passwordField's stringValue()
        do shell script "security add-generic-password -a gmailpdf -s email -p '" & passwordDefault & "' -U"

        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_


end script
```

When compiled and added to the PDF Services folder I get this error (the app is named GMail PDF:
`The document “Google News.pdf” could not be opened. GMail PDF cannot open files in the “Portable Document Format (PDF)” format.`

How do I get an AppleScriptObjC application to accept the file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have any file-handling capabilities in your app yet, so you'll have to implement `application:openFile:` from `NSApplicationDelegate`:

From the [NSApplicationDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename
```

Which, in AppleScriptObjC, would be:

```
on application_openFile_(theApplication, filename)
    -- your PDF handling code goes here
end application_openFile_
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple alias of the application in the PDF Services folder should be enough to pass the PDF to the app.

Any script as a PDF Service will be sent 3 arguments: File title, job options, and path to the PDF.